# adding a new dom element, want to rebind

Tags: jquery

After adding a new DOM element after a ajax request, the click event for the newly added item doesn't work.

I tried to first unbind then bind, but I get an error.

```
$(".someclass").unbind("click", someEvent);
$(".someclass").bind("click", someEvent);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? (in theory)?

Comment: Can you post the code that adds this element to the DOM?  hgimenez gives a valid alternative (to use the live function), but what you're trying to do should work without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use [live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) instead of bind().

```
$('.someclass').live('click', someEvent)
```

Comment: I've never seen live() make a page laggy, I would test it out. If it does for you then you have way too many elements with a class of .someclass ;). Also, see this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse%5Fthread/thread/432a0d9caae734db