# How to bind events with jQuery in django admin when new *Inline is added

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin, jquery-events

I made a jQuery function that binds some fields, but it doesn't work when I add a new inline.

The main problem is that I don't know how to detect the insertion in DOM and bind it to my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions to bind to form elements. They will continue working even after you insert new form elements, and you don't need to re-attach the event handlers every time.

Related questions:

- [Binding dynamically created elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238616/binding-dynamically-created-elements-in-jquery)
- [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)
- [jQuery how to bind onclick event to dynamically added HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)
- [adding a new dom element, want to rebind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474558/adding-a-new-dom-element-want-to-rebind)

Comment: maybe this answer need to be updated, since live is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-row a').click(my_function)
```

as long as `my_function` does not include `return false;` it shouldn't interfere with the existing functionality of that button

Comment: i think $("selector").live("click",my_function()) is a better solution, you do it just one time at the beginning and don't need other selector, it's simpler.

Comment: It refuses to bind to the hyperlink, but it does to .add-row.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions above do not work for this particular problem. I'll file a bug and ask if they can assign an ID to that link button, or fix it another way.

Edit: bug filed https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16359

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but just in case anybody else is wasting hours trying to wrap their heads around this (like I'm doing now), here is how to do it: listen to the formset:added event and you've got it:

```
$(document).bind('formset:added', function(e) {
    console.log("New inline formset added: ", e.target)
});
```